# Sherlock is going against the Beast with PowerShell

Tags: programming-challenge, powershell

I ran into [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-the-beast) a couple of times today and thought I could tackle it with PowerShell. I refused to look at other peoples approaches to this hoping to complete it on my own. I'm sure the general idea is the same in either case. I have included more comments than I would normally to help people not familiar with the language/challenge.

> A Decent Number has the following properties:
>
> 1. Its digits can only be 3's and/or 5's.
> 2. The number of 3's it contains is divisible by 5.
> 3. The number of 5's it contains is divisible by 3.
> 4. If there are more than one such number, we pick the largest one.
>
> ## Constraints
>
> 1≤T≤20
>
> 1≤N≤100000
>
> ## Input Format
>
> The first line is an integer, **T**, denoting the number of test cases.
>
> The **T** subsequent lines each contain an integer, **N**, detailing the number of digits in the number.
>
> ## Output Format
>
> Print the largest Decent Number having **N** digits; if no such number exists, tell Sherlock by printing -1.

```cs
# Split the lines in the string passed as string array. Cast each value as an integer
$inputNumbers = $args[0] -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object{[int]$_}

# Cycle the numbers. Amount determined by the first line.
for($inputIndex=1;$inputIndex -le $inputNumbers[0];$inputIndex++){
    # Create a loop that runs for the number of passes in the current line of input.
    # Count down from the number until 0
    $highestNumber = $inputNumbers[$inputIndex]..0 | ForEach-Object{
        # Check to see if this digit combination is a decent number.
        # If it is then we pass it thru the pipeline and stop the loop.
        If(($_ % 3) -eq 0 -and (($inputNumbers[$inputIndex] - $_) % 5) -eq 0){
            ("5" * $_).PadRight($inputNumbers[$inputIndex],"3")
            # If we get a result then this is the highest. Exit the loop.
            continue
        }
    }

    # Check the value of $highestNumber. It is possible that for this pass there
    # are no decent numbers. Nulls evaluate to false.
    if($highestNumber){$highestNumber}else{-1}
}
```

**Usage**

Save the above code as a ps1 file. Run it passing a multi-line string parameter.

```
.\Get-DecentNumbers.ps1 "4
1
3
5
11"
```

Answer (score 5):

1. I'm no powershell expert but if spaces sprinkled around here and there would make the code more readable. So instead of this:

   ```
   for($inputIndex=1;$inputIndex -le $inputNumbers[0];$inputIndex++){
   ```

   it would read like this:

   ```
   for (inputIndex = 1; $inputIndex -le $inputNumbers[0]; $inputIndex++) {
   ```

   Less crammed and easier to read I'd say.
2. Your outer `for` loop could be expresses as a `ForEach` which would yield cleaner code:

   ```
   ForEach ($N in $inputNumbers) {
       # Create a loop that runs for the number of passes in the current line of input.
       # Count down from the number until 0
       $highestNumber = $N..0 | ForEach-Object {
           # Check to see if this digit combination is a decent number.
           # If it is then we pass it thru the pipeline and stop the loop.
           If (($_ % 3) -eq 0 -and (($N - $_) % 5) -eq 0) {
               ("5" * $_).PadRight($N, "3")
               # If we get a result then this is the highest. Exit the loop.
               continue
           }
       }

       # Check the value of $highestNumber. It is possible that for this pass there
       # are no decent numbers. Nulls evaluate to false.
       if ($highestNumber) { $highestNumber } else { -1 }
   }
   ```
3. As for the algorithm: You kind of brute force it which is usually not the intend of these programming challenges. I have outlined a slightly better algorithm in [my answer to another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/119173/30346) trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: I have literally done 0 of these types of things before. There is only so many PPCG posts I can read before I had to start trying. Thanks for the information. Just trying to soak in your other answer now.